# How can I get json from this webpage using requests or other libraries?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How can I get json from this webpage using requests or other libraries?

code:

```py
request_url = 'http://tour.tmon.co.kr/api/direct/v1/airtktintlapi/api/search/dataList'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '1011',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Host': 'tour.tmon.co.kr',
    'Origin': 'http://tour.tmon.co.kr',
    'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                   +'(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36')
}

jsonObj = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers).json()
```

error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. It was just server problem, when you did call (IMHO).

Comment: thanks.
If you go into a web page, there is Payload instead of parameters, which I suspect is the reason.
Or it seems to be blocking the access of the bot.
Anyway, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: This moment server returns response (But gives you information about error) with 'application/json' content type and status_code 200, so you can use .json() method. you are doing it correctly.

Comment: But if you are expecting different json data,,, This is other problem. Maybe more headers required (for example 'Referer').

Comment: you're requesting an answer from the server without providing your parameters (city of origin of something else since you're looking for plane tickets)